# How to disable second multi-select dropdown if nothing is selected in first drop down?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am using below code, but the second dropdown box always remaining in the disable state after selecting value form first dropdown. How to disable and enable second multi-select dropdown based on the first multi-select dropdown?

```
<select id="multi-select-demo" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">  
<option value="analysis">Analysis</option>
<option value="algebra">Linear Algebra</option>
<option value="discrete">Discrete Mathematics</option>
<option value="numerical">Numerical Analysis</option>
<option value="probability">Probability Theory</option>
```

```
<select id="multi-select-demo1" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
<option value="programming">Introduction to Programming</option>
<option value="automata">Automata Theory</option>
<option value="complexity">Complexity Theory</option>
<option value="software">Software Engineering</option>
```

and my enable /disablescript is below:

```
<script>
$('#multi-select-demo').change(function(e){
$('#multi-select-demo1').prop('disabled', !$(this).val());

});
$(function(){
  $('#multi-select-demo').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#multi-select-demo1').prop('disabled', true);
});
</script>
```

My script for multi-select, I am not able to paste. How to disable/enable second multi-select dropdown if nothing is selected on first multi-select dropdown?

Answer (score 2):

The multi-select `value` is an array so check for the `length`.

```
$('#multi-select-demo').change(function(event) {
  $('#multi-select-demo1').prop('disabled', !$(this).val().length);
});
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/842gpv77/1/**

Comment: HI @Miguel. As tried as you have mentioned. But it not working in my eclipse. I am displaying dropdowns with checkbox using bootstrap. Socond dropdown is going to disable. But I am not able to enable it after selecting values from the first drop down. My dropdown is showing like following example

Comment: Could you please help me on my mentioned url .Thank you in advance

Comment: @Muskan working example using bootstrap multi-select http://jsfiddle.net/2os4t5fh/9/

Comment: Thank you @Miguel . It is working now. But one issue is there . I am using following code to make fixed width of dropdown. If we try using fixed width script and your suggested script. Together it is not working . Coudl you please help me if it can work with fixed width code also. Please find my below code multiselect . Thank you in advance. Please find my code below:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#multi-select-demo').multiselect({
            buttonWidth: '500px'
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .multiselect-container {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

Comment: can you suggest me code for fixed 100% width of select id and should work with your mentioned code also

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the condition so that if no options are selected, the select is disabled. The most reliable way to do that is if the *selectedIndex* property is -1.

You also need a listener on the reset button so that when resetting the form, the select is set back to disabled:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('multi-select-demo').addEventListener('change',function(){
    document.getElementById('multi-select-demo1').disabled = this.selectedIndex == -1;
  },false);
  
  document.getElementById('formReset').addEventListener('click',function(){
    document.getElementById('multi-select-demo1').disabled = true;
  },false);
}
```

```html
<form>
<select id="multi-select-demo" multiple="multiple">  
  <option value="analysis">Analysis</option>
  <option value="algebra">Linear Algebra</option>
  <option value="discrete">Discrete Mathematics</option>
  <option value="numerical">Numerical Analysis</option>
  <option value="probability">Probability Theory</option>
</select>
<select id="multi-select-demo1" multiple="multiple" disabled>
  <option value="programming">Introduction to Programming</option>
  <option value="automata">Automata Theory</option>
  <option value="complexity">Complexity Theory</option>
  <option value="software">Software Engineering</option>
</select>
<input id="formReset" type="reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [bootstrap-multiselect Methods](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods)

You can simply use the `.multiselect('disable')` and `.multiselect('enable')` methods to do that.

Use the `onChange` prop in your multi-select config and check for `this.$select.val()`, which will give you an array of the selected values, if anything is selected of course. If nothing is selected it will return `null`.

Here is an example.

```js
var $sel1 = $('#multi-select-demo');
var $sel2 = $('#multi-select-demo1');

$sel1.multiselect({
nonSelectedText: "Choose from Bar",
  onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
  if (this.$select.val() && this.$select.val().length) {
    $sel2.multiselect('enable')
  } else {
    $sel2.multiselect('disable')
  }
}
});

$sel2.multiselect({
disabledText: 'Select Bar first'
});
```

```css
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>

<select id="multi-select-demo" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="analysis">Analysis</option>
  <option value="algebra">Linear Algebra</option>
  <option value="discrete">Discrete Mathematics</option>
  <option value="numerical">Numerical Analysis</option>
  <option value="probability">Probability Theory</option>
</select>

<select id="multi-select-demo1" multiple="multiple" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="programming">Introduction to Programming</option>
  <option value="automata">Automata Theory</option>
  <option value="complexity">Complexity Theory</option>
  <option value="software">Software Engineering</option>
</select>
```